# Get share/like count for different url/bogposts/articles

Tags: facebook, api, facebook-graph-api

I am looking for a method to get share/like count for each of the blogposts/articles which I create on my website. Interested in Facebook, LinkedIn and Twitter but Facebook is the most important right now.

Lets take this website as an example: https://googleblog.blogspot.com/

I have found a method to find this out for each url, but that will make it a lot harder for me as I would need to do it manually for each URL.

This is the query I used to get data for a specific URL:

https://graph.facebook.com/v2.7/?id=https://googleblog.blogspot.no/

Is there any method to get data for each and every url which contains: "company name" or something like this?

Will appriciate all the help I can get here.

Answer (score 0):

No, there is no “wildcard” for Open Graph object URLs.

You can however request data for multiple URLs in one go, using the `?ids=foo,bar` syntax – https://developers.facebook.com/docs/graph-api/using-graph-api/#multiidlookup

This theoretically works for up to 50 ids in one request (although with the ids being URLs in this case, you might only be able to request less, due to URL length limitations.)